# Find parameter from line equation

Tags: geometry

How can I solve the following problem:
Given the line equation: $$d:(a-1)x+(a-2)y-a+3=0$$ and $$ Ox\cap d={A}$$  $$ Oy\cap d={B}$$ How can I find a knowing that 1/OA^2+1/OB^2=10. This seemed really easy and I tried solving it but its from an old exam and it doesn't have answers. I found a is 33/8 after calculating the distance between O and A and O and B and solving the last equation.Is it correct this way?[image]

Comment: Your notation confused me a bit. Are OA and OB your abscissa and ordinate, respectively? And if so, how are they different from $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar Looks to me like $A$ and $B$ are the $x$- and $y$-intercepts of the line. I.e., $Ox$ is the $x$-axis and $Oy$ is the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $A(\frac{a-3}{a-2},0)$ and $B(0,\frac{a-3}{a-1})$.  From here I get two solutions, namely $a=17/4$ and $a=-5/2$.

Comment: I found the same points but when I solve the equation wouldn't I have 1/((a-3)/(a-2))+1/(a-3/a-1) which is (a-2+a-1)/(a-3)=10

Comment: Added a pic but I realised I forgot to square them ,I resolved it again and got the values thank you :(

Comment: You're welcome.